# concatenar resultados mysql

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una base de datos donde se guardan varios registros de un pedido
Esta es mi base de datos:
[image: tabla]

Lo que deseo obtener es lo siguiente:
id_plato,cantidad,llevar;id_plato,cantidad,llevar;.....

es decir la concatenacion del id_plato, la cantidad y llevar en un solo resultado separado por ;

intente esto:

```
$query = "
select id_plato,cantidad,llevar,GROUP_CONCAT(id_plato SEPARATOR ' - ') AS xd,
from pedidos_detalle 
where id_pedido='2010250332153396'
group by id_pedido
";

$res = $bd->query($query)->fetch_assoc();


var_export($res);
```

pero me arroja error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean

Nota: el error es propio del codigo ya que elimino el group_concat y si me funciona normal

Comment: Tienes un error de sintaxis en la instrucción SQL, tienes que quitar la última coma, antes del FROM, aquí: `AS xd,` ... por eso te da el error, pues no funciona tu consulta.

Comment: no es eso brother, ya lo hize sin esa coma e igual me sigue dando error :(

Comment: ¿Qué error da ahora? ¿Verificaste que el nombre de la tabla y las columnas es correcto? ¿Verificaste que la conexión a la BD es correcta? Debes poner la pregunta con el código que tienes. En el actual lo que se ve es el error de sintaxis que te he señalado en mi anterior comentario.

Comment: como te digo amigo, no tiene nada que ver con la conexion, todo esta verificado, porque si elimino el group_concat si me lee los otros datos

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon el código que tienes. Si la conexión está bien y los nombres de tabla/columna también y no tienes esa coma de más, la consulta no debería dar error.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(',', id_plato, cantidad, llevar) SEPARATOR ' - ') AS resultado_concatenado

ese era el codigo que necesitaba bro

Comment: El error era la coma inicialmente. De todos modos, la consulta que indicas cómo solución tiene deficiencias, por ejemplo, me parece que deberías aplicar `SUM()` a la columna `cantidad`.

Answer (score 0):

Solucion:

```
$query = "
select 
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(',', id_plato, cantidad, llevar) SEPARATOR ' - ') AS resultado_concatenado
from pedidos_detalle 
where id_pedido='2010250332153396'
";

$res = $bd->query($query)->fetch_assoc();


var_export($res);
```

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(',', id_plato, cantidad, llevar) SEPARATOR ' - ') AS resultado_concatenado
```

Comment: Por favor procura leer [answer], ¿qué cambiaste?, considera que una respuesta que es solo código es dicifil de asimilar para los demás